# PHP/jQuery - Submit a form checkbox values using GET onChange

Tags: php, jquery, forms, get

I am trying to submit checkboxes values (category names) from a form using the `GET` method. I am generating a key (integer) for each of the category names using a custom PHP functions. My `page.php` file is used for my URL `www.mywebsite.com/shop`

On my `page.php`:

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="sidebar-filter-form">
    <ul class="sidebar-filter-options-list">
        <?php foreach($category_list as $key => $row): ?>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="<?php category_key($row->category_name, "k");?>"> <?php echo $row->category_name;?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</form>
```

In `custom.js`:

```
$(function(){
     $('#sidebar-filter-form').on('change', function() {
        this.form.submit();
    }); 
});
```

I am trying to retrive the category keys for sorting my products on `page.php` using:

```
$category_keys = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null;
```

I would like to know why my form isn't reloading my page and changing my URL to retrieve my keys to something like `www.mywebsite.com/shop?category[]=43&category[]=6&category[]=22` (with probably `%5B` and `%5D` for Unicode `[` and `]`)

Comment: Are you sure that the 'change' event fires? Are you sure that `this.form` selects the form?

Comment: I dare to recommend you do better in another way. Why not use a class for all the checkboxes and do with jQuery a "each" that returns an array with the chosen input?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I would eventually like to add some sort of delay (1-2 sec) before refreshing the page that would allow the user to select multiple checkbox values before submitting the form. I want to try to avoid a submit button.  `this.form` can trigger sucessfully an alert message on change, so I believe it does select the form.

Comment: Given that `#sidebar-filter-form` selects the form itself, `this.submit()` would seem more appropriate. Suggest you get it working with a submit button then finally address auto-submit. Also, for a better user experience, consider making your app an SPA, with non-refreshing AJAX requests.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thanks a lot for the feedback, `this.submit()` did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Another solution will be make an each of each checkbox. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?
    $items = array(
        array('id' => 20, 'name' => 'Tomato'),
        array('id' => 32, 'name' => 'Milk'),
        array('id' => 34, 'name' => 'Sugar')
    );
    ?>
    <ul>    
<?  foreach ( $items as $comboItem ) : ?>
        <li><input data-id="<?=$comboItem['id']?>" type="checkbox" class="pick-me"/><?=$comboItem['name']?></li>
<?  endforeach; ?>  
    </ul>
    <br>
    <button class="get-all">Get all items selected</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            $('body').on('click','.get-all', function() {
                var items = [];
                $('.pick-me').each(function() {
                    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                        items.push($(this).attr('data-id'));
                    }
                });
                console.log(items);
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```